# C++ can local class reference be passed to a function?

Tags: c++, local-class

I would like to know if the following is allowed:

```
template < class C >
void function(C&);

void function() {
  class {} local;
  function(local);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not allowed right now. But it's supported in C++0x. The current Standard says at `14.3.1/2`

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

That said, if the function is also local, there's no problem

```
void f() {
  class L {} local;
  struct C {
    static void function(L &l) {
      // ...
    }
  };
  C::function(local);
}
```

Comment: bummers.  Is there clean alternative for named tuples (which is what been trying to do)?

Comment: Ah. I think local function will do it for me.
Thanks

Comment: You mean `class { int a; int b; } x; function(x);` ? Not possible: the type of `x` is local. You have to go your way with pair, or make x's class not local (the variable `x` can still be local). Put the class into an unnamed namespace for example. I usually consider functions inside local classes like this a bit hacky :) But i'm glad i could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed if you use polymorphism instead of templates. Or if you don't need to extend the interface seen by `function`, simple inheritance will do.

```
void function( ABC & );

void function() {
  class special : public ABC {
      virtual void moof() {}
  } local;
  function(local);
}
```